# convert a set of flash files into SCORM Package for moodle

Tags: flash, moodle, scorm

I have a set of flash files embedded into one html file. Is there anyway I can convert this into a SCORM package to be used in Moodle. Or is there a better way to embedd this as a course in moodle LMS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a SCORM Package. I don't know if there is a better way to do it in Moodle.

To create a SCORM Package, put all your files into a zip, and add a imsManifest.xml file, the content of this xml file should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<manifest identifier="Flash content" version="1.3" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" xmlns:adlseq="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3" xmlns:adlnav="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3" xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                        http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd
                        http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd
                        http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd
                        http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>CAM 1.3</schemaversion>
  </metadata>
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="Flash_content" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="flashPlayer.html">
      <file href="FlashFile.swf" />
      <file href="AnotherFlash.swf" />
      <file href="FlashPlayer.html" />
    </resource>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

The manifest must be in the zip root, the hrefs in the imsmanifest.xml are relative to the file itself.
I didn't tested the manifest, so, maybe there is something missing, but you can start there.

Hope this helps.